# Extract the matching information between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have to 2 dataframes df1 and df2 with the below contents:

```
In [1]: df1
Out[1]: 
          text                  
0 ABC ZZ KEY778 20225 
1 XXX11 K ABC 14452GXX
2 ABC ZZ AZZXG112 
3 DCB AA112G AXXX
4 DCB AA15G AXR12-1

In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
  A         B                             
0 ABC ZZ    KEY778 
1 XXX11     XXX11 K            
2 ABC        
3 DCB       AA112G AXXX
```

I want to check if the content of column A or B of df2 exists in the content of text column of df1. If it's true, I create 2 new columns (for A and B) in df1 and put this corresponding element.
The final result should be like this:

```
In [3]: df1
Out[3]: 
          text                 correspondingA      correspondingB
0 ABC ZZ KEY778 20225          ABC ZZ              KEY778 
1 XXX11 K ABC 14452GXX         XXX11               XXX11 K
2 ABC ZZ AZZXG112              ABC
3 DCB AA112G AXXX              DCB                 AA112G AXXX
4 DCB AA15G AXR12-1            DCB
```

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

In df2 column A you have 'ABC ZZ' that does exist in the first row of df1, but at the same time, in df2, you have 'ABC' that also does exist in the first row of df1, so Im not sure what data would you put on the correspondingA column.

Also, if you just want to check, lets say, row 2 of df2 only with row 2 of df1 we have another problem, as df1 has more rows than df2.
Either way, not sure what you would like to do